# How does web browsing in a terminal services session work?

Tags: terminal-services

Specifically, how does the data from a web server get routed to the correct session when it is sent back to the terminal server.

Is the session ID sent as part of the HTTP headers?

There's a very good reason I need to know, but it's fairly complicated and not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP/IP to send data over a network.  TCP/IP works by using both a source port and destination port.  Most people are familar with destination ports (http=80, https=443, smtp=25, etc).  Before a connection can be established, the OS provides the application with a source port to *send data out of* to the destination port.  When the response comes back, it's destination was the other packets source port.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Erik.  So from that am I correct to assume that in a terminal services environment, browsers running in separate sessions will all be assigned different ports with which to send data out of?

Comment: Sessions make no difference, this occurs on just about any OS for any tcp/ip connection.  This occurs on every request from a browser, even when browsers request files in parallel on a non-terminal server (each request has it's own source port).

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Erik Philips in comments above.